# How do I resequence icons in the "Applications Menu (Gnome extension) by FMueliner"

Tags: appmenu

(a) I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

At first I did an upgrade from 20.04.10 LTS, which failed miserably when PYTHON3 deleted itself and then failed to re-install -- and as a result the rest of the upgrade continued to DESTORY my entire system. I then discovered that the system backups were no good and I was unable to recover from that disaster.  I was then forced to do a complete new install which is what I am now trying to run..

(b) Since I have a NVidia Display card, my Display Manager is X11.
(c) I have also installed some Gnome Extensions like "Applications Menu by FMueliner"

When I click on "applications" on the top menu bar, I get a popup window that has a list of Application Categories on the left side, and a list of Icons on the right side.

(1) How can I resequence the icons on the right hand side?

Because of the way UBUNTU uploaded new stuff, The ICON for "ThunderBird" is at the top of the list, "Files" is second, and "Firefox" is at the bottom of the list. I would prefer to see a sequence of "Files", "Firefox", "Thunderbird", and then all else.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't find any Gnome extension called *Applications Menu* for 22.04. Please [edit] your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category that is opened when you open the "Applications" menu is "Favorites". The applications included there are these that are pinned on your dock (or dash), and they are also ordered accordingly. Thus, to change the order in the "Applications" menu, reorder your favorites on the dock.